# Have had to sleep vs Had to sleep

Tags: tense

There have been times in my life when I have had to sleep empty stomach because I had no money to buy myself a meal.

Vs

There have been times in my life when I  had to sleep empty stomach because I had no money to buy myself a meal.

Which one is right ? The first one - have had to ( talking of life experiences) or the second one - (talking about past activity)

Comment: Some people might think that because you started with Present Perfect *(**have been*** rather than Simple Past ***were**)*, you should repeat that with ***have had to***. I'm not one of them - so far as I'm concerned it's generally at least "okay" (often, *preferable*) to revert to simpler tense *as soon as possible* after a Perfect form. Perfect forms tend to be a bit "heavy", so it's usually a good idea to minimise their use.

Comment: We usually say: *to sleep **on** an empty stomach*

Comment: I would keep it simple: "There have been times in my life when I *slept on an* empty stomach because I had no money to buy myself a meal." I don't think perfect tenses are necessary since the time frame is clear in context.